# Importar funciones entre módulos en Python

Tags: python

Quisiera importar funciones entre dos módulos en python pero Ocurre un error de importación

modulo1.py

```
from modulo2 import Mundo
def Hola():
     print "HOLA"

Hola()
Mundo()
```

modulo2.py

```
from modulo1 import Hola
def Mundo():
     print "MUNDO"
Hola()
```

en el caso real solo se llama la función **Mundo** en el modulo1

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta en la función `Mundo` del `mudulo 2` los paréntesis. No estoy seguro, pero que dos módulos se importen entre sí, generaría una especie de bucle infinito. No tiene mucho sentido que un módulo que se importe, intente importar al módulo que lo invoca, si ese modulo está presente ya, sería una paradoja.

Comment: Se me olvido poner los paréntesis, pero no es ese el problema, el problema es que es un proyecto estructurado y tienes razón, entra en un bucle infinito, ya lo logre solucionar aun que me queda que si importo una función  el resto del modulo va con el.